# ChromeDriver issue in 111 version

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
    ChromeOptions ch = new ChromeOptions();
    ch.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(ch);
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method addArguments(String[]) in the type ChromiumOptions<ChromeOptions> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

How to resolve addArguments issue?

Answer (score 1):

The line `ch.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");` is expecting the array of strings and you are passing a string, so remove `s` from  `addArguments`

Like you have to change your code

***From***

```
ChromeOptions ch = new ChromeOptions();
ch.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(ch);
```

***To***

```
ChromeOptions ch = new ChromeOptions();
ch.addArgument("--remote-allow-origins=*");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(ch);
```